# TensorFlow: Using computed results earlier in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's a small example where I want to sample a batch based on the values I get at the end of a computation.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

conditional_val = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

print("get labels")
images, labels = get_img_and_label(data_dir, batch_size, conditional_val)

print("infer")
logits = inference(images)

print("define loss")
loss = compute_loss(logits,labels)

for i range(1000):
    if i < 1:
        _, loss_value = sess.run([loss])
    else:
        _, loss_value = sess.run([loss],feed_dict={conditional_val: index})

    index = int(np.around(i*loss_value)[0])
```

Here is where I define the function that gets the batch.

```
def get_img_and_labelS(data_dir,batch_size,conditional_val=0):
    with open(data_dir) as datafile:
        data = json.load(datafile)

    inputs = data.keys()
    input_names = []
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        input_names.append(data_dir + inputs[i] + '.png')

    for f in input_names:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

    images = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(len(input_names)):
    # Load images with PILLOW (PIL Library)
        my_img = Image.open(input_names[i])
        images.append(np.array(my_img))
        labels.append(data[inputs[i]][0])

    images = images[0*conditional_val:20*conditional_val]
    labels = labels[0*conditional_val:20*conditional_val]

    return(images,labels)
```

It keeps giving me the error:

```
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type Tensor to integer
```

Is there any nice way to do what I'm trying to do? 
Thanks!

Comment: at which line is the `IndexError` happening?

Comment: It happens at this line.  images = images[0*conditional_val:20*conditional_val]

Comment: oh I see, `conditional_val` is an "unevaluated Tensor", you have to evaluate it in TensorFlow runtime to get it's actual value that you can pass to numpy. IE, something like `val = sess.run(conditional_val)` and then use `val` in your slicing

Comment: I set conditional_val here feed_dict={conditional_val: index})
index = int(np.around(i*loss_value)[0])
on those two lines at the end of the first block of code so it's set after the .  The problem is that it is a tensor and not an integer that I can use to index into an array.  Actually you're right I need to update my code to reflect it's initialized.